# How to use wildcard in string replacement?

Tags: string, powershell, shell, wildcard

I'm new to PowerShell.I encountered a problem when I tried to replace certain character with some new characters in a string using wildcard.What's wrong with the code?

```
$file = "want apple banana want want"
$file.Replace("w*t","wanna")
```

PowerShell outputs "want apple banana want want", but why not "wanna apple banana wanna wanna"?

I would be grateful if someone could help me.:)

Answer (score 3):

`String.Replace` doesn't support pattern matching, it only does literal replacements:

```
PS ~> "want apple banana want want".Replace("want", "wanna")
wanna apple banana wanna wanna
```

I'd suggest using the `-replace` regex operator:

```
PS ~> "want apple banana want want" -replace "w.*?t", "wanna"
wanna apple banana wanna wanna
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality in neither PowerShell nor .NET framework to do an actual *wildcard* replace. I recommend to use the *RegEx* `-replace` operator as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75603525/7571258). This gives you all the possibilites of a wildcard and even more flexible ways to search and replace.

If you really want to do a *wildcard* replace, a simple implementation could translate a wildcard pattern into a *regular expression* pattern and then use the `-replace` operator to do the actual replacement:

```bash
Function WildcardReplace( $Text, $Wildcard, $Substitute ) {
   $regex = [regex]::Escape( $Wildcard ).Replace('\?', '.').Replace('\*', '.*?')
   $Substitute = $Substitute.Replace('$', '$$')
   $Text -replace $regex, $Substitute
}
```

**Usage:**

```bash
$file = "want apple banana want want"
WildcardReplace $file "w*t" "wanna"
WildcardReplace $file "w??t" "wanna"
```

**Output:**

```
wanna apple banana wanna wanna
wanna apple banana wanna wanna
```

**Remarks:**

- `[regex]::Escape( $Wildcard )` [escapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-7.0) any characters in the wildcard pattern that have special meaning in a RegEx pattern, by prepending them with a backslash (`\`).
- `.Replace('\?', '.')` turns the `?` wildcard into the equivalent RegEx pattern which is `.`.
- `.Replace('\*', '.*?')` turns the `*` wildcard pattern into a RegEx pattern that matches *non-greedy*, which is what you want here. If the RegEx were `.*` instead, it would match as many characters as possible, in which case wildcard `w*t` (-> RegEx `w.*t`) would match the **whole** input string `want apple banana want want`.
- `$Substitute.Replace('$', '$$')` escapes the `$` character in the replacement pattern, by doubling it, because the `$` character has special meaning in a [RegEx substitute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions).